# App would crash when I try to load map and Google Maps isn't loading the maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This is a bus tracking app where the location is retrieved from firebase.
In the main Activity I select the bus number and click start, from there the bus number is taken to the MapsActivity with the help of intent. At first the Map wouldn't load and I tried fixing it but it made it worse as the app now crashes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, Please help me out here.

**MainActivity (Bus Selection)**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private
    RadioGroup route;
    public static final String ARG_FROM_MAIN = "arg";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations");
    public String someVariable;
    TextView numberbs;
    Button getLocationBtn;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    Button busb1;
    Button busb2;



    Button busb3;
    Button busb4;
    Button busb5;
    Button busb6;
    Button busb7;
    Button busb8;
    Button busb9;
    Button busb10;
    Button busb11;
    Button busb12;
    Button busb13;
    Button busb14;
    Button busb15;
    Button busb16;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        numberbs = findViewById(R.id.busnotext);
        btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.signoutbtn);
        getLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.getLocationBtn);


        numberbs = findViewById(R.id.busnotext);
        busb1 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn1);
        busb2 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn2);
        busb3 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn3);
        busb4 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn4);
        busb5 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn5);
        busb6 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn6);
        busb7 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn7);
        busb8 = findViewById(R.id.bustbtn8);
        busb9 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn9);
        busb10 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn10);
        busb11 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn11);
        busb12 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn12);
        busb13 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn13);
        busb14 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn14);
        busb15 = findViewById(R.id.bustbtn15);
        busb16 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn16);

        busb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb2.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb3.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb4.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb5.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb6.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb7.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb8.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb9.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb10.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb11.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb12.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb13.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb14.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb15.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb16.setOnClickListener(this);

        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", someVariable);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

       btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                //startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

/**
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Ref", someVariable);
        startActivity(intent);
 */
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.busbtn1:
               someVariable ="BUS1";
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 1");
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS1");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn2:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 2");
                someVariable ="BUS2";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS2");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn3:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 3");
                someVariable ="BUS3";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS3");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn4:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 4");
                someVariable ="BUS4";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS4");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn5:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 5");
                someVariable ="BUS5";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS5");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn6:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 6");
                someVariable ="BUS6";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS6");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn7:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 7");
                someVariable ="BUS7";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS7");
                break;
            case R.id.bustbtn8:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 8");
                someVariable ="BUS8";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS8");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn9:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 9");
                someVariable ="BUS9";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS9");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn10:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 10");
                someVariable ="BUS10";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS10");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn11:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 11");
                someVariable ="BUS11";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS11");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn12:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 12");
                someVariable ="BUS12";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS12");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn13:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 13");
                someVariable ="BUS13";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS13");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn14:
                someVariable ="BUS14";
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 14");
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS14");
                break;
            case R.id.bustbtn15:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 15");
                someVariable ="BUS15";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS15");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn16:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 16");
                someVariable ="BUS16";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS16");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**MapsActivity (Where the bus location is shown)**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //String value_latitude = "0";
    // String value_longitue = "0";
    Double longi = 0.0;
    Double lati = 0.0;
    // String message = "BUS1";
    Double latitude = 0.0;
    Double longitude = 0.0;
    String vali;
    Button Backp;
    TextView BusNO;
    private CountDownTimer timer;


    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   private DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();

    // private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading... Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Backp = findViewById(R.id.backbuttonmap);
        BusNO = findViewById(R.id.busnotext);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String str = bundle.getString("message");
        vali = str;
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapip);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        BusNO.setText(vali);
        timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 8000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                try {
                    timer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getBussGeo();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }.start();

        Backp.setOnClickListener(this);
        Backp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                timer.cancel();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        /*
        if (mMap != null) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lati, longi);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(vali));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
        */
    }

    public void getBussGeo() {
        myRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child(vali);
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Log.e("Long", "onDataChange: " + longitude);
                    Log.d("lato","onDataChange" + latitude);
                    lati = latitude;
                    longi = longitude;
                    if (lati == 0||longi == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "BUS NOT ACTIVE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {

                        if (mMap != null) {
                            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lati, longi);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(vali));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 17));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The Application has been opened!


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The Application has been closed!
        timer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.manavchordia.aplparent">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat:**

```
2019-10-26 00:04:11.020 11141-11141/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.manavchordia.aplparent, PID: 11141
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manavchordia.aplparent/com.manavchordia.aplparent.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.manavchordia.aplparent.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 

2019-10-25 23:50:40.948 1752-2486/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

What I did:
Remove the map from the XML Layout and added it again as it showed ''(Earlier it said MapView), now it shows nothing(blank screen) and it crashes.

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backbtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backbuttonmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="318dp"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/busnotext"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="673dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/audiowide"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your `activity_maps.xml` file

Comment: I have added the code in the snippet above.

Comment: `findFragmentById(R.id.map)` instead of `findFragmentById(R.id.mapip)`

Comment: No it still doesn't work.

Comment: If it's still crashing, what's the stack trace now?

Comment: okay I had repeated the steps for creating a maps activity, it doesn't crash now. The map loads when used with the simulator but when I upload it to the playstore the map is just a blank screen. I don't know where to debug as everything works fine with the simulator .

Comment: Is your API key restricted? If so, are you using different API keys for your debug build and release build? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#fingerprint